# C# Get year part from date

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime

I am converting an existing vb application to .net, in the existing code i found the condition below.How can I write this condition in C# ? Thanks in Advance

```
if CLng(Right(request("yr"),4))=CLng(Year(Date())) then
//I am confused only in Year(Date()) how can I replace these functions in C#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Year(Date())` can be written as `DateTime.Now.Year`